# how to show array input out of loop in angular js

Tags: arrays, angularjs

Following is the code in angular js to show the array input value .but i want to show the array input value out of the angular js loop

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

    <html ng-app="">

        <body ng-init="names = ['Sam', 'Harry', 'Sally']">


            <p>names: {{names}}</p>
            <h3>Binding to each element directly:</h3>
            <div ng-repeat="feature in names">
              Value: {{feature}}
                <input ng-model="feature">                         
            </div>


      </body>
    </html>

    </html>
```

Comment: What actually do you want to achieve? Your code is perfectly fine and you can access data from names any where in the html just by providing index like {{name[2]}}

Comment: If you plan to work with angular you need to get a better fundamental understanding of working with javascript arrays and objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a controller for the view and in that:
`@scope.names = ['Sam', 'Harry', 'Sally']`

Then access each entry in the view with {{names[index]}}

Comment: can u edit my code and make much easier to understand ?

Comment: just replace `<p>names: {{names}}</p>` with `<p>name1: {{names[0]}}</p>` to see what I mean.

Comment: @ Andre Kreienbring  i want to display  Value: {{feature}} any where in page it ,and can be out of loop

Comment: Because of this: `ng-repeat="feature in names"` {{feature}} is names[0] in the first iteration, names[1] in the second and names[2] in the third.